# Flutter firebase does not initialize

Tags: flutter, firebase

am getting this error.
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

I have updated all firebase packages in .yaml, i still have this error

```
E/flutter (11230): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter (11230): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:242:7)
E/flutter (11230): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11230): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (11230): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11230): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40:31)
E/flutter (11230): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11230): #3      main (package:mossbets/main.dart:22:3)
E/flutter (11230): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11230):
```

Let me also add i have made the call to initialize firebase. Once i remove the initialisation the app works fine but without firebase

Comment: can you share your `android/build.gradle` file? did you add the google service dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by the new changes with Firebase CLI with firebase options. So to solve this do add :

in your terminal

```
$ flutterfire configure
```

then in your `main`

```
// Import the generated file
import 'firebase_options.dart';

...
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
...
```

You probably going to be asked to authenticate your firebase account so you' ll run this in your terminal

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

this article will help you...start from step 4 [Article](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-firebase-flutterfire-cli/)

Answer (score -1):

add these two lines to your main.dart main function

```
void main() async{

 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // initializing the firebase app
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

   
runApp(MyApp());

}
```

Comment: I have both lines but the error persists

Comment: have you tried 'flutter clean' and  'flutter pub get upgrade'