# The method 'initializeApp' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseApp'

Tags: flutter, firebase

why doesn't initializeApp() work? do i need another package? I get this error : **The method 'initializeApp' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseApp'**

```
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
        
        void main(){
           Firebase.initializeApp();
           FirebaseApp.initializeApp();
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirebaseApp.initializeApp() can't be used in the main.dart, it's for MainActivity and you need these packages

In MainActivity

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck;
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.playintegrity.PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory;
```

In pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_app_check: ^0.1.1+8
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the documentation that says you should call a method initializeApp on FirebaseApp.  The method really doesn't exist as the error message says.

You just get a FirebaseApp object back from `Firebase.initializeApp()`.

See:

- https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage/
- https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/

Comment: I use it as described here by google: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider?authuser=0&hl=de#java_1

Comment: That is an example for Java or Kotlin, not Dart.  Use the Flutter docs instead: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers?hl=en&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using one of the latest firebase packages you need to use the new Firebase CLI way of configuring. Check this out https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/. Overall it's the installation process of FlutterFire across all supported platforms.
You can also follow through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73774075/10698100