# Getting error Firebase exception in flutter code about initialisation

Tags: flutter, dart, class, push-notification, initialization

Getting Firebase exception in flutter code about initialisation. I have already initialised it in main function. getting error on first line of code where fire store collection initialised.

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/models/core/user_details.dart';

```
class UserInfoService{
  CollectionReference userInfoCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userInfo');
UserDetails userDetails =UserDetails();

  addData(UserDetails? userInfo) async {
    await userInfoCollection.doc(userInfo!.user!.sId).set(userInfo.toJson());
    return true;
  }


  Future<UserDetails> getInfo(String? userId)async{
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await userInfoCollection.doc(userId).get();
    if(ds.data() != null){
      return UserDetails.fromJson(ds.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }
    return UserDetails();
  }

}
```

main.dart with Firebase initialisation:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/push_notification/notification.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/routes/router.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/auth_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/company_details_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/password_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/profile_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/reward_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/trans_history_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/transaction_manager.dart';
import 'models/helper/service_locator.dart';
import 'ui/routes/routnames.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:new_version/new_version.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MyApp());
 

  Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) {
    FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.registerNotification();
    FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.configLocalNotification();
  });

  

  Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) async {
    FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.registerNotification();
    // FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.navigate();
    FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.configLocalNotification();
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('topic1');
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  });

  

  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
 
  await setupServiceLocator();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(393, 786),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => getIt<AuthManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<CompanyDetailsManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<TransactionManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<PasswordManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<RewardManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<ProfileManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<TransHistoryManager>()),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                onGenerateRoute: Routers.generateRoute,
                navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                initialRoute: splash),
          );
        });
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This should not happen if you correctly initialised firebase. Would you mind showing us the code of how you actually initialised firebase

Comment: I have initialised it in main method

Comment: @Davis I have edited my question with main method

Answer (score 1):

it says that

```
 No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created
```

this is usually happen when you're not initialize firebase properly, but you have initialized firebase in your code. instead of initializing like this, try new method of initializing using  [`flutterfire`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?hl=en&authuser=0#install_the_firebase_cli)

- Install the [`Firebase CLI`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?hl=en&authuser=0#install_the_firebase_cli) and log in (run firebase login)
- From any directory, run this command:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

- Then, at the root of your Flutter project directory, run this command:

```
flutterfire configure --project=blind-crushes
```

This automatically registers your per-platform apps with Firebase and adds a `lib/firebase_options.dart` configuration file to your Flutter project.

To initialize Firebase, call `Firebase.initializeApp` from the `firebase_core` package with the configuration from your new `firebase_options.dart` file:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

// ...

await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

Then, add and begin using the [Flutter plugins](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?hl=en&authuser=0&platform=ios#available-plugins) for the Firebase products you'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

So try the new way of initialising a firebase app in flutter. Follow this link that also contains an article.
[Link to how to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73774075/10698100)